# Did this only become possible in "Avengers: Endgame" because of a certain destroyed item?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

In *Avengers: Endgame*, did the time travel only become possible due to the Infinity Stones being destroyed?

During the events of *Ant-Man and the Wasp* we learn that the original Wasp has been living in the quantum realm for around 30 years, however when she gets rescued at the end she's aged according to the "normal" flow of time outside the quantum realm. And as far as I remember she doesn't mention it only feeling like 30 hours either.

However while

> Scott Lang is stuck in the quantum realm for 5 years he gets out saying it only lasted 5 hours for him.

Did this new flow of time only become possible due to Thanos

> destroying the Infinity Stones

and thus breaking the flow of time, and creating the possibility of time travel?

The Sorcerer Supreme seems to back this up when she tells Banner that the Infinity Stones are what created the flow of time.

I would find it unlikely that Hank Pym wouldn't have investigated the possibility of this before, had there been any hints towards it from Janet.

And if that is true, then wouldn't time travel become impossible again once the Stones are brought back to the current timeline?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## NO

It's established in the end-credits of *Ant-Man and the Wasp* that the Quantum realm has "Time Vortices" and this is where Janet ends up **independent of the Time Stone**.

The Quantum Realm does not appear to be affected by the existence (or otherwise) of the Infinity Stones.

Indeed, this is a major plot point in *Endgame* since time travel *through the Quantum Realm* is still possible even though Thanos destroyed all the Infinity Stones.

The difficulty was creating a method of navigating the Quantum Realm and these time vortices to travel through time.

In *Endgame* they develop the Time GPS to know where and when they are in space-time.

There is certainly a discrepancy in the experiences of Janet and Scott while in the Quantum Realm but while Janet ages, she somehow manages to stay alive without food or water for 30 years.

Scott says that it felt like 5 hours so it seems likely that the *flow* of time in the Quantum Realm is quite different to the *regulated* flow in the main "timeline".

Indeed, in *Endgame* Scott says that the rules of the Quantum Realm aren't "like they are up here, everything is *unpredictable"*.

Comment: If I recall, the stones weren't destroyed until several days after the snap. Janet appeared to have experienced the normal passage of time but if Scott's experience was due to the stones being destroyed, he would have been stuck for those full days before time would have started going wonky. But he was only gone for five hours total, suggesting that whatever happened was happening before the stones were destroyed.